# How to develop desktop application in wpf that looks correctly in all the system resolution?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created desktop application in screen resolution of **1280 X 1024** by setting page.xaml width and height of 1272 and 893 respectively.

but after creating set up file when i run in another system which has less resolution some buttons are not visible.

Please guide me how to develop windows application in wpf that works on all screen resolution with proper alignment.

Comment: Do you need to specify resolutions?  Set the page to start up full screen and then use the anchors to layout your page (and they will adapt with the size)

Comment: to make your GUI to work correctly you **must not** harcode you page's width/heigth.

Comment: you should design for lower resolution first & since WPF is resolution independent , it will get adjusted for higher resolution automatically.

Comment: @Johan are you saying that he needs to have WindowState = "Maximized" ?

Answer (score 1):

Use relative size instead of absolute , Do not hardcode values for height and width of any control

Comment: Not really an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's an [article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ee308410(v=vs.85).aspx) about developing **DPI independent** WPF applications.

And as stated above, the whole point of using WPF is not to hardcode any dimensions, but to lay out elements using containers. Doing so will lead to **resolution independent** application.